# Higher ML model accuracy negatively impacts pricing optimisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science, price

I work with some supermarket data to do some Sales Forecasting. So, I do regression and my model has 25+ columns.

My final goal is to make an optimal pricing recommendation-optimal discount tool. So, I brute-force different discounts-product_prices (I know not the best way). Then, by using every time the new price I run my model to predict the new Sales Forecasting and by multiplying with the current tried price I get the current "predicted" revenues, so that I can find the max, and so have the optimal price/discount.

However, when I try different prices, I see no difference in my model's predictions, because my model has 25+ columns, and price is just one of them, and doesn't matter a lot, especially in regression.

What can I do about it? If I lower the number of factors I use, I will get a model with worse accuracy but with a bigger price impact. Is it some kind of trade-off? Is there a better solution out there? Do you have an alternative POV for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Since your dataset is not available i may just share some rough ideas;

*However, when I try different prices, I see no difference in my model's predictions, because my model has 25+ columns, and price is just one of them, and doesn't matter a lot, especially in regression.*

This seems like a 'feature engineering' problem. I would recommend;

1. to start displaying the correlations of your features
   (**https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html**)
   and think about the potential reasons of positive and negative
   correlations. This may help you to drop some features and generate some new ones..
2. if you haven't already tried, i would recommend you to apply feature scaling. (**https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html**)
3. if you can give more details about the dataset and your work, i
   believe someone much more experienced than myself will give a better
   and more precise answer to your question

good luck...